# Why is this function not unbounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have a real valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta \ s.t. \  |x-1| \ge \delta \rightarrow  |f(x) - f(1)| \ge \epsilon $$

Then it is claimed in my exam that

$$ \lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$$

BUT

$$ f \ \text{is not unbounded}$$

I think these statements are contradictory, as $f$ is bounded if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}, \text{ s. t. }  \forall u \in \mathbb{R}  \ |f(u)| < M $

But if:
$$ \lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$$

Then $\exists$ a sequence of values $u_1 , u_2 ... $ such that $f(u_i)$ is an unbounded sequence.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I posted an answer arguing why $f$ should be unbounded without fully reading your question; sorry about that.  You're absolutely right, if $f$ were bounded we can't have $\lim \limits_{|x| \to \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I can see why
$\lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} |f(x)| = \infty
$:

In
$\forall \epsilon > 0, 
\exists \delta \ s.t. \  
|x-1| \ge \delta \rightarrow  
|f(x) - f(1)| \ge \epsilon
$,
choose
$\epsilon$
very large
and you get
$|f(x) - f(1)| \ge \epsilon$
so
$|f(x)| \ge \epsilon- |f(1)|
$.

I agree with you that
"$f \ \text{is not unbounded}
$",
which,
to me,
is the same as
$f$ is bounded,
contradicts this.

So,
I am not sure
what is going on here.

Go ahead,
somebody:
Prove me wrong.
(Won't be the first time.)

Comment: I don't think you're wrong.  Either OP misinterpreted the exam question, or there is a typo on the exam.

Comment: https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf, Question 60, page 54.

Comment: Actually I think i know the issue,  "equivalent" is the condition they are harping on.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Where in that question do they suggest $f$ is bounded?

Comment: $f$ is bounded is an answer choice, but its wrong. But I think that the subtlety is that the question is asking not "which of these choices is correct given the set up of the question" but "which of these choices is EXACTLY what the question assigns to $f$ "

Comment: so the error is in my interpreting of the question

Comment: @frogeyedpeas So is your question "Why is the answer NOT C?"

Comment: yes, and i now know why :)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Ok, good.  Yeah, you can have an unbounded function that doesn't satisfy this $\epsilon-\delta$ property.  Can you think of one?  That's why it's not the right answer. :)

Comment: Yea $y = \frac{1}{x}$ would be such an example

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Hmm, are you sure?  I was thinking more along the lines of something that is unbounded as you approach $x=1$.  Like taking $f(x) = \begin{cases} \tan(\frac{\pi x}{2}) & 0 \leq x < 1  \\ 3 & x \not \in [0,1) \end{cases}$, or something like that.  That way, the only way you approach infinity is as $x$ approaches $1$ (from the left in this case).

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I've undeleted my posted answer, which contains an explanation in words of the $\epsilon-\delta$ property.  Hopefully it shows you why this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $f(1)$ is a constant.

By the definition of your function, we are assured no matter how big we make $\epsilon$, we can find some $\delta$ such that if $x$ is more than $\delta$ away from the value $1$, then $f(x)$ will be more than $\epsilon$ away from $f(1)$.

So, we can make $\epsilon$ as large as we want, and we are assured we can still find $x$ values such that $f(x)$ is at least $\epsilon$-distance from $f(1)$.  I hope it's clear from this that $f$ must then be unbounded.

If it were bounded, then we know for all $x$, $f(x)$ must be in some set $[-M,M]$ for some positive $M$.  But if that's true, then $f(x)$ cannot be more than $2M + 1$ away from $f(1)$ (why?).  But we just said we can always find $x$ values so that $f(x)$ is as far away as we want from $f(1)$.  So that's a contradiction, and so $f$ is unbounded.